# Is it safe to modify the document Object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, object

I'm wondering if I can modify the document Object like this, to guarantee the existence of document.getElementsByClassName(), or if there is some limitation on modifying document in some browsers:

```
if(typeof document.getElementsByClassName !== 'function')
    document.getElementsByClassName = function(class_name){
        // Custom function
    };
```

Comment: You can, but that doesn't mean you should.

Comment: [This article from kangax](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) may be of interest to you.

Comment: Also interesting in this regard: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. The `document` object behaves like every other object in Javascript, so it's extensible.

Comment: The `document` is a host object, and so its behavior isn't required to meet all the rules of the spec.

Comment: it is not required to, but will in most cases. Most problems won't apply to this case since we are only editing 1 object, not a prototype. I don't have any IE6 around to test, but it would surprise my if that wouldn't work.